# Coordinating CASpringAnimation with UIView.animate(usingSpringWithDamping:)

Tags: ios, spring, animation, uiview, calayer

I have a series of `CALayer`s that I need to animate with a spring, using `CASpringAnimation`. I also have a series of `UIView`s that I need to animate in coordination with the `CALayer`s. Now, because most `UIView` properties are exposed through `CALayer`, I'm able to easily animate `UIView` `bounds`, `transform`, `opacity` etc. through its `CALayer`, letting me use `CASpringAnimation` for most `UIView` properties.

However, not all `UIView` properties are exposed through `CALayer`, for example, `UIVisualEffect`. So, if I need to coordinate the animation of, e.g., a `UIVisualEffect` along with the spring animation of a `CALayer` property, I'd need to use a `CASpringAnimation` in conjunction with a `UIView.animate(usingSpringWithDamping:)`.

In .playground, coordinating animation properties — like initial spring velocity and damping — between methods has proven difficult. They never seem to align perfectly.

**TL;DR** How can I best coordinate spring animations of `CALayer` properties with `UIView` properties that aren't exposed through `CALayer`?

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to solve... Any luck?